# Is there any way of executing the already executed code in java

Tags: java

Is there any way of executing the already executed code in java.

for example in the main method i have int variable a = 10; and later point in time say suppose at the end of execution i will check some conditions on its(a's) value and if the condition fails then i want it to execute from the beginning.

there may be some other scenarios also, right now i have this.

Edit: without looping and methods. which i know. 
        like goto statements in c++. and dont think only for the above stated example there might be some other example which might need the way i wanted.

Comment: make said code a function and just call it again in a loop while the condition is not met...

Comment: how about refactoring that code out of main to a dedicated function, and run it in a loop with your condition?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why wouldn't you use a loop here?

Comment: Are you actually looking for a `goto`?

Comment: bang on MAK. while editing you commented.

Comment: @gurukulki: I really meant it as a joke. How come you don't want loops or recursion but have no problem with `goto`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why can't you just do something like this?

```
   do {
       a = processSomething();
   } while(a != 10);
```

**EDIT**: if you can't use a proper loop construct, then recursion is your only real choice.. something like this:

```
int rFunction(int a) {
    // if we found our needed value, return it
    if(a == 10) {
        return a;
    }

    a = whatever();

    rFunction(a); // call again with new value   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a function, or create a loop.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is: No, there is no way to do that in Java.  You would have to use a loop or recursive method.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(some_check_of_some_sort)
{
   // do stuff
}
```